# I need to list all resources in all subscriptions

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I need to list all resources in all RGRPs on all subscriptions.
all what is there basically.

I try to do it with regex but does not work.

Comment: I'm assuming `az resource list` is not what you're after. Can you be a bit more specific about what you need, what you tried and how what you're getting is not what you need?

Comment: Id need something like that:

az resource list --subscription * --resource-group *

Comment: Unless you restrict it, it will list all resources on all subscriptions you have access to. You can't obtain access by restricting what you're seeing (which is what "regex" would do). You should capture the output of `az resource list` and try to make sense of what you're missing - if you're missing something specific that you're sure you should be seeing, perhaps ask a question about that problem specifically.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've done, along with expected and actual output. Currently, your question only contains a requirement with no work shown. Also fyi this doesn't seem like a programming question (unless you're trying to make this happen in code via management api?). If it's with command-line tools, this belongs on ServerFault (but you still need to show your work, not just a requirement).

Comment: @Grismar >> az resource list lists only resources for active subscription. I need something global, for all subscriptions and resource groups

Comment: @DavidMakogon
here is my scripting for all VMs
#! /bin/bash
for sub in $(az account list --query [].name -o tsv); do
    az vm list --subscription $sub --query [].name -o tsv 2>/dev/null
done

Comment: @eswues - That needs to be an *edit* to your question. Code should never be placed in a comment, as it's unformatted and very difficult to read (plus, it can never be edited).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource graph query (kusto/kcl) for that

```
Resources
| project name, type, location
| order by name asc
```

See also here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/starter?tabs=azure-cli#list-resources

PowerShell:

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources | project name, type, location | order by name asc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all resources on all subscriptions:

```
#! /bin/bash 
for sub in $(az account list --query [].name -o tsv); do 
    az resource list -o tsv --subscription $sub 2>/dev/null 
done
```

Check if your resource exists and print subscription of it

```
#! /bin/bash 
for sub in $(az account list --query [].name -o tsv); do 
    az resource list -o tsv --subscription $sub 2>/dev/null --query [].name -o tsv 2>/dev/null | grep -i $1 && echo "SUBSCRIPTION:  $sub" && exit
done
```

Let me know if there is simpler way.

Cheers

Comment: Keep in mind that you also need to ensure that your logged in client does not filter out any subscriptions under "subscriptons" on https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade
If so, change the filter, and do an `az login` again to show all subscriptions.